# Need to change node's path to CCK value

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a content type that has been turned into a Feature named "Earth News".  It includes an optional CCK field called "Source URL".  When that CCK field is not blank I want the site visitor to be able to click on the teaser and go straight to that URL.

I've added the following preprocess function to the .module file for this feature:

```
function earth_news_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = node_load($vars['nid']);
  $path = drupal_lookup_path('alias','node/' . $node->nid);
  $url = $node->field_se_news_source['und'][0]['url'];

  path_save(array($path,$url));
}
```

The path_save is throwing a fatal error:

```
Only variables can be passed by reference
```

Am I on the right path?  What's that error all about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact [path_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_save/7) is expecting a single argument passed by reference. In such case, you cannot use a literal array; you could pass a variable containing an array, or the value returned by a function that returns a reference, but the value expected as argument needs to be an associative array containing the following keys:

- source: The internal system path
- alias: The URL alias
- pid: (optional) Unique path alias identifier
- language: (optional) The language of the alias

In your case, the code should be like the following one.

```
function earth_news_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  $path = array(
    'alias' => drupal_lookup_path('alias','node/' . $node->nid),
    // You can also use the following line instead of the previous one.
    // 'alias' => drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $node->nid),
    'source' => $node->field_se_news_source['und'][0]['url'],
  );

  path_save($path);
}
```

As side note, [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) makes available the node object as `$vars['node']`; there is no need to load the node.